# Is it possible to embed a resource with an accessibility modifier different than the default public?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, embedded-resource, access-modifiers

By default, **embedded resources** are set `public` accessibility modifiers.

So says `ILSpy` when I look into a sample program with token embedded resources.

I have found this page below that claims it is possible to set them to `private`, but it is unclear how to make this happen via `VS2019` or manually editing the `csproj` file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/resource-compiler-option

Any clues appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The csproj schema does not seem to support this setting. The path to the schema file is

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Core.xsd

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Commontypes.xsd

The csproj files are in fact MSBuild files.

Comment: Appreciate the effort even if it is not the answer. I was looking for those and couldn't find them. Thanks. Good karma to you.